# How to Copy/Paste Sheet Data Without Including ActiveXButtons

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste

Problem:

I have a sheet that contains values, formulae and ActiveX buttons. The ActiveX buttons are used to append some of the data and copy/paste all of the values/formulae from the active worksheet to another a worksheet in a separate workbook.

Right now it works fine with one exception. When it pastes the copied range into the new workbook/worksheet it also pastes in the ActiveX buttons along with their respective code.

I would like to know if there is a way to select everything, less the ActiveX buttons, add it to the clipboard and then paste it in as usual.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
Application.CopyObjectsWithCells=False
'do your copy
Application.CopyObjectsWithCells=True
```